# List of top ten products based on sales

Tags: sql, postgresql

I would like to write an optimal sql query for this question and just wondering if there is a better solution or this would be the best possible solution. Please share your thoughts on this. Thanks.

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT product_id,ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( ORDER BY SUM( quantity*price) DESC ) AS rownum
  FROM orders
GROUP BY product_id  
)
WHERE rownum <= 10;
```

Comment: The only other way I could imagine writing it us using a cross apply with a `limit of 10` but I'm not sure it would be faster.

Comment: Do you also need the ranking of each product to be included (as you do above with `ROW_NUMBER`)?

Answer (score 1):

I would expect the fastest in Postgres to be:

```
SELECT product_id
FROM orders
GROUP BY product_id  
ORDER BY SUM(quantity*price) DESC
LIMIT 10;
```

However, I would expect this to be only marginally faster than your query.  The bulk of the effort is aggregating the orders for each product, and I think any query needs to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your query will give best performance. I tried to compare it with below simple query as well and both queries are either taking same time or your query is performing better. Now other physical design parameters may impact in actual environment.

```
select top 10 product_id, SUM( quantity*price) from orders group by product_id
order by SUM( quantity*price) desc
```